# Worksheet Visible = true not working with formular in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which works very well, not i have added a formula in cell B27 and sheet name in A27. B27 has a formula with changes the value from blank to "PC", this is not triggering the sheet to unhide. It unhides if i select the cell and press enter, but not when the formula changes the cell.

```
Sub worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Target  ' Loop over all modified cells

    If Not Intersect(Range("B2:B27"), cell) Is Nothing Then
        ' Something in column B was changed.
        Dim wsName As String
        wsName = cell.Offset(0, -1).Value  ' Get sheet name from column A
        If wsName <> "" Then  ' Only if the name column is filled
            On Error Resume Next   ' Begin of manual error handling
            ' Show or hide the sheet
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible = (cell.Value <> 0)
            
            If Err.Number = 9 Then
                ' Runtime error 9 happened, the sheet does not exist.
                MsgBox "Sheet " & wsName & " is not present in this workbook."
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0        ' End of manual error handling
        End If
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

It there a way to add a change in (D2-D27) will unhide sheet(4) "PCL"?

Comment: The `Worksheet.Change` event does not fire when formulas recalculate. You need the `Worksheet.Calculate` event.

Comment: Hi,so i just change the declaration?

Comment: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name. i have this error now?

Comment: No, because the `Worksheet_Calculate` event handler has no parameters, i.e. there is no `Target`.

Comment: Sorry i am very new to all this, would i need two events?

Comment: My guess is yes.

Comment: It there a way to add a change in (D2-D27) will unhide sheet(4) "PCL"?